# Convert X8B8G8R8 to R8G8B8 C++ code

Tags: c++, ogre3d

I would like to convert a hardware pixel buffer that is in the format X8B8G8R8 into unsigned int 24 bit memory buffer.

Here is my attempt:

```
 // pixels is uin32_t;
 src.pixels = new pixel_t[src.width*src.height];





    readbuffer->lock( Ogre::HardwareBuffer::HBL_DISCARD );
            const Ogre::PixelBox &pb = readbuffer->getCurrentLock();

            /// Update the contents of pb here
            /// Image data starts at pb.data and has format pb.format
            uint32 *data = static_cast<uint32*>(pb.data);
            size_t height = pb.getHeight();
            size_t width = pb.getWidth();
            size_t pitch = pb.rowPitch; // Skip between rows of image
            for ( size_t y = 0; y<height; ++y )
            {
                for ( size_t x = 0; x<width; ++x )
                {
                    src.pixels[pitch*y + x] = data[pitch*y + x];
                }
            }
```

Comment: So what problem are you having ?

Comment: And the outcome/problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do

```
uint32_t BGRtoRGB(uint32_t col) {
    return (col & 0x0000ff00) | ((col & 0x000000ff) << 16) | ((col & 0x00ff0000) >> 16)
}
```

With

```
src.pixels[pitch*y + x] = BGRtoRGB(data[pitch*y + x]);
```

Note: `BGRtoRGB` here converts both ways if you want it to, but remember it throws away whatever you have in the `X8` bits (alpha?), but it should keep the values themselves.

To convert the other way around with an alpha of `0xff`

```
uint32_t RGBtoXBGR(uint32_t col) {
    return 0xff000000 | (col & 0x0000ff00) | ((col & 0x000000ff) << 16) | ((col & 0x00ff0000) >> 16)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another thing. How would I convert back rgb to xbgr

Comment: Right, this function converts both ways but would throw away the higher bits (`X8`?). You would have to get these 8 bits from somewhere.

Comment: if you want to keep the 8 higher bits in the converted number (I'm not sure how what you're using to parse it would like that), change the first bitmask of `0x0000ff00` to `0xff00ff00` If you do that, it would be fully symmetrical.

Comment: Just assume the alpha to 0xff